# Test two conditions with shouldly

Tags: c#, shouldly

I have a property in a class

```
public class User {
    public string FiscalCode {get; set;}
}
```

And i want test the property fiscal code with two condition.
The test is ok if fiscalcode is null or fiscalcode is verified by a method

```
public bool FiscalCodeIsCorrect(string fiscalcode) 
{
    ....
}
```

How can i test in a single line with shouldly if one of the two conditions is verified ?

I want use this condition in a test project so the line of code could be

```
user.FiscalCode.ShouldBeOneOf()
```

But i can't because `null` and `string` are two different types.

Comment: `if(FiscalCode == null || FiscalClodeIsCorrect(FiscalCode)`? Assuming the method is defined on `User`.

Comment: i want use shouldly, so i'm looking for a line of code such as 

user.FiscalCode.ShouldBeOneOf(...)

Comment: And what´s the problem on having an `||`, which is what you should use obviously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ShouldBeOneOf` can not deal an function, so I think the simple way is using `ShouldBeTrue`

```
(FiscalCode == null || FiscalClodeIsCorrect(FiscalCode)).ShouldBeTrue();
```

Comment: shingo likes shouldly :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use basic `||`:

```
if ( FiscalCode == null || FiscalCodeIsCorrect(FiscalCode) )
{
   //something
}
```

`||` is logical OR operator. This evaluates to `true` in case at least one of the operands evaluates to `true`. Also, note that it does short-circuiting which means if the `FiscalCode` is `null` it will not call `FiscalCodeIsCorrect` at all.

Comment: "so i'm looking for a line of code such as user.FiscalCode.ShouldBeOneOf(...) "

Answer (score 0):

what @Martin Zikmund sugessted is right too but in your case both `Null` and `FiscalCodeIsCorrect` should be ok. So putting the `null` validation logic in `FiscalCodeIsCorrect` should be a better solution, then you wont have to validate if null every time. 
so here is what i mean

```
public bool FiscalCodeIsCorrect(string fiscalcode) 
{
    if (fiscalcode == null)
       return true;
    //....You code here
}
```

now you only have to chack

```
if (FiscalCodeIsCorrect(FiscalCode) )
{
   //something
}
```